# Android Gridlayout is not resizing and placing itself in the center of the screen

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am not sure why my GridLayout is not appearing in the center of the screen. Also I want it to be resized so it can fit any screen of any device I use.

Here's the xml I am using to create my UI:

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:columnCount="4"
    >
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/selectPlayerDropdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        />
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="#C0C0C0"
        />
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView13"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView14"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView15"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

And this is what it looks like: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding the android:gravity=center to GridLayout as well? I haven't used GridLayout yet, but if I understand the layout_gravity and gravity attributes correctly, the former is to align itself within its container while the latter is to align its children within itself. I could be wrong... sorry if I am.